# Where would the global settings be for popup windows in an ASP.NET project?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, css

I inherited a project from a group member who has since left my group and I have been running into popup window issues.  I have checked my entire project time and time again but I cannot find the settings that globally set popup window settings.

All popup windows from the website are set to a specific height and width and have the toolbar, menubar, resizing capability turned off.

I have checked: site.master, site.master.cs, home.aspx, home.aspx.cs,  all javascript/html, CSS, .js files...etc but nothing changes the popup window settings.  Is there another spot I should be looking to configure popups?

Comment: Since you didn't post any of the files how should we know? Script files sound likely but there are a number of ways to pull something like that off.

Comment: Ultimately that's controlled by the client-side code that calls `window.open()`; maybe it's just hard-coded into the various popup generation routines.

Answer (score 2):

Search your javascript files (`*.js`) for calls to `window.open(`. The third parameter is the settings object which controls the properties of the window that opens.

If it refers to a variable instead of a hardcoded string, search your javascript files for the declaration of that variable.

Comment: It could be coming from a number of places that are not so easily searched. Hell, it could be from an imported 3rd party assembly for all we know.

Comment: The code that opens the window exists in the browser as javascript but in the source code it could be compiled away in some random assembly, or streamed from a source file, or pulled in dynamically through jsonP, any number of different ways. My point was that as it it stands there is no way for us to give anything better then a shot in the dark guess.

Comment: @asawyer so F12 on the page and search the javascript, as my answer suggests :P